# Why does some part of my selenium (python) code gets executed after commenting the code?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get the Google+ URL link of the reviewers of Chrome extensions using selenium with python. The code that I am using is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException, \
    NoSuchElementException
import sys
import time
import traceback

def create_browser(first_page=None):
    #print "Starting"
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('/home/user/ChromeDriver/chromedriver')
    if first_page:
        browser.get(first_page);
    #print "Done."
    return browser

def close_browser(browser):
    browser.close()

def wait_find_elements_by_class_name(driver, name):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 7:
        try:
            elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(name)
            break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            time.sleep(1)
            counter += 1
            elem = None
    return elem

def wait_find_element_by_xpath(driver, path):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 7:
        try:
            elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path)
            break
        except NoSuchElementException:
            time.sleep(1)
            counter += 1
            elem = None
    return elem

browser = create_browser()
#print 'loaded'
try:
        #print "Fetching URL"
        url = 'https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/movies-showtimes/aaaagimjfioddedkjmggbabjgblfdnkd/reviews'
        print url       
        browser.get(url)
        while(1):                       
            passJS = 0
            gPlusLinks = wait_find_elements_by_class_name(browser, 'comment-thread-displayname')            
            #print "Bla"
            for link in gPlusLinks:             
                passJS += 1
                if passJS <= 2:
                    continue
                l = link.get_attribute('href')
                if l != "javascript:void(0)":
                    print l
            '''time.sleep(3)
            try:
                a = wait_find_element_by_xpath(browser, './/a[@class="webstore-eh webstore-ib-Vg"]')
                a.click()
            except ElementNotVisibleException:
                break
            except AttributeError:
                break   
            print "Scrolled and clicked."
            time.sleep(3)   ''' 
except:
    print "'For loop' exception: ", sys.exc_info()[0]
    for tb in traceback.format_tb(sys.exc_info()[2]):
        print tb

print "Done"
```

My problem is when I uncomment the commented part (`time.sleep(3)` on  line 61 to `time.sleep(3)` on line 70) my program terminates without printing the Google+ URLs (i.e the `print l` statement). However, after commenting that part it prints the URLs properly.

Can anyone explain why this happens and how do I prevent it? I really need the code to get executed in order. I could understand if the code was multithreaded but it is not. So I don't know how to explain this.

Comment: Well, you just do the break on exception. You should trow it again to print something.

Comment: I am breaking because I want the `while` loop to terminate if the element is not found.

Comment: What are you expecting to be printed?

Comment: The Google+ links of the users who reviewed the extension.

Comment: "terminates without printing anything" seems unlikely to me given that you have `print` statements that are not affected by the code which is commented out. It would help if you could make it explicit in your question what prints and what does not print.

Comment: @Louis - Thanks. I edited my question to specifically say whats not being printed. Its the `print l` statement that want to get printed